# D3 Transition Path Left And Shift Up/Down Simultaneously

Tags: d3.js

Following the tutorial of Mike Bostock on Path transitions [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/),  I am trying to create an interpolated line chart that not only shifts through time but also transitions the y-scale / y-axis, such that is always fits to the lower and upper bounds of the data.

Some background information: The line is clipped by a clipPath and is shifted to the left whenever a new data point is added. Each new data point is added by the tick function, which also transitions the path to slide to the left.

Now the problem is, when I update the y-axis domain, it jumps to the new position. However, I would like it to smoothly transition up or down, similar to how it shifts along the x-axis. The solution probably lies in transforming the scaling of the path based on the new maximum of the data. Is there any way to achieve this or would it require a different approach by building a custom d3.interpolator() for interpolating the path?

```
function tick() {

  // Push a new data point onto the back.
  data.push(random());

  // Redraw the line.
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("transform", null);

  // Slide it to the left.
  d3.active(this)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
    .transition()
    .on("start", tick);

  // Pop the old data point off the front.
  data.shift();
  let max = d3.max(data, (d) => {
    return d;
  });

  y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-1, max])
  .range([height, 0]);

  d3.select('g .axis.axis--y').transition().duration(500).call(d3.axisLeft(y))

  d3.select('g .axis.axis--x').transition().duration(500)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
}
```

I have created a jsfiddle which demonstrates the problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gtjcL3xo/1/).

Comment: Have you tried adding as `ease` function to your transition? Explanations here: https://observablehq.com/@d3/easing-animations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by using the external `d3-interpolate-path` library from  [here](https://github.com/pbeshai/d3-interpolate-path). Instead of transitioning the path using a transform, I interpolate the path with the old data and the path with the new data using `d3.interpolatePath`. Where `previous` is the old path and `current` is the new path with the newly added data point.

```
d3.select(this)
  .attr("d", lineOld)
  .attr("transform", null)
  .transition().duration(500).ease(d3.easeLinear).attrTween('d', (d) => {
    let previous = d3.select(this).attr('d');
    let current = line(d);
    return d3.interpolatePath(previous, current)
  }).on("end", tick);
```

The Jsfiddle with my solution can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/42a5pjke/1/)